# Are there any audits on this site?

Tags: support, reviewing

I've done around 50 reviews for Arqade. I have not gotten a single audit yet. On StackOverflow I would have gotten at least two or three by now.

Are there actually any audits on this site? If so, are they not being shown since we have such small review queues (which means "robo-reviewing" is not as big of a problem)?

Comment: I've done several thousand reviews, and I am pretty sure I haven't had an audit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/285368):

> This is currently active only on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, Programmers, Ask Ubuntu, Mathematics, and Puzzling.

In other words, audits aren't active on Arqade.

This is probably because (as you said) our review queues are usually pretty short. Barring exceptional circumstances (such as when the Late Answers algorithm was changed), I have never seen the queue go above 15. Hence, not much motivation to robo-review.

Comment: Looks pretty clear to me. Thanks!